# Makefile CMD long path limit

Tags: windows, cmd, makefile, gnu-make

When when I have long paths in my project (250+ characters), when I trigger my makefile it can't find the include files.

Is there a way to fix this instead of renaming folders to decrease path length?

Also if my long directory is E:\longpanth\includes and my makefile can't find it. How come if I cd E:\longpanth in CMD it finds the directory correctly, could it be something else than CMD, like make.exe or something?

Note: I'm on windows 10 and I use CMD to trigger my makefile

Comment: You can try the [subst](https://ss64.com/nt/subst.html) command.

Comment: @Stephan I know about the subst but is there another way to make it accept longer paths?

Comment: You can try the short notation (`for %a in ("C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\") do echo %~sa`)

Comment: @Stephan, if my long directory is E:\longpanth\includes and my makefile can't find it. How come if I cd E:\longpanth in CMD it finds the directory correctly, could it be something else than CMD, like make.exe or something?

Comment: You should always use forward slashes, not backslashes, in makefiles.  Just as a general rule.  Don't know if it will help since you say you're invoking commands with CMD.

Comment: @MadScientist could you tell my why?

Comment: Because make is a tool that comes from UNIX/POSIX and in that environment, directory separators are forward slashes and backward slashes are used for escape characters, not directory separators.  If your problem only happens with long paths then it's not related to this but in general it's a good practice: most Windows tools (compilers etc.) will accept both forward and backward slashes as directory separators.